# Is $\mathbf{hTop}$ locally cartesian closed?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

The category $\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces and continuous maps is infamously not cartesian closed. However, it is weakly cartesian closed (weakly = no uniqueness condition in universal property of exponential). Moreover, the category of spaces and *homotopy classes* of maps [$\mathbf{hTop}$ is cartesian closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453698/is-the-homotopy-category-cartesian-closed).

My question is: is $\mathbf{hTop}$ *locally* cartesian closed?

Comment: Without knowing the definitions, I can't be sure, but often something being "locally _____" follows from it being _____ globally. Why do you doubt this here?

Comment: @MikePierce Locally cartesian closed means all slices are cartesian closed. A category can be cartesian closed but not locally cartesian closed (eg. $\mathbf{Cat}$).

Comment: I think I have just realised the answer: $\mathbf{hTop}$ is *not* locally cartesian closed because the slices don't even have products, for products in slices are pullbacks in the base category and $\mathbf{hTop}$ does not have pullbacks (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4018667/pushouts-in-category-of-topological-spaces-modulo-homotopy?rq=1).

Comment: And there I was worrying about exponentials!

Comment: Could you give a definition of *weakly cartesian closed*?

Comment: Maybe delete the question or change it then?

Comment: I think you're really going to have to go all the way up to the $\infty$-category of spaces being locally cartesian closed. And please note, especially since I leave this implicit in my old answer at your link, that it's the category of topological spaces with weak homotopy equivalences inverted that's cartesian closed, *not* the category of topological spaces and homotopy classes of maps. This hTop is also the category of *CW complexes* and homotopy classes of maps.

Comment: @Tyrone Exactly the same as *cartesian closed* (which you can easily find) but omit "unique" in the universal property of exponentials.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Happy to delete if that is the consensus, but at the moment I think there is still some discussion/clarification to be had. What would you suggest as a change?

Comment: Well you know now it’s not locally Cartesian closed. So what’s left of the question? Any outstanding issues? Put that in the question and change the title.

Comment: @KevinArlin Right, and presumably you means locally cartesian closed in the $\infty$ sense?
Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out -- I had glossed over it. So is it not true that you get cartesian closure if you do not restrict to CW complexes (with homotopy classes of maps)?

Comment: @ssp8 Right on both points.

Comment: @KevinArlin Just to clarify, do you know/expect the $\infty$-category of spaces to be locally cartesian closed, or are you just saying that to have any chance you must go to $\infty$? I guess the issue with pullbacks resolves in the $\infty$ case, but what about right adjoints to these? It's not clear to me, but then again I'm not too savvy with $\infty$-stuff.

Comment: It’s true. The $\infty$-category of spaces is even the archetypal $\infty$-topos. But this is not at all something verifies in a few minutes. It takes four or five chapters of Cisinski’s book, which I think is the quickest treatment available.

Comment: @KevinArlin btw, it's just the uniqueness part of the universal property of exponentials that holds up to homotopy, right? The relevant diagram commutes on the nose, as $\mathbf{Top}$ is weakly cartesian closed?